# Use Variable data in Microsoft Access 2010 Data Macro

Tags: ms-access, macros, ms-access-2010

I am new to Access 2010 Data Macros!

In my database I have a function that returns the UserId of the current user. The function returns pubUserId (Public pubUserId as integer)

I have a Data Macro that writes a new record to a table. This works very well. I want to improve the macro by:
* including a call to this function to confirm pubUserId (I then know 100% who the user is!)
* write pubUserId to a field in the table. (This will then keep a record of who did what!)

How do I do the above two steps?

Answer (score 0):

Your macro should RunSql, and your Sql expression should append the result of the pubUserId function at the end the SQL INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

I created a query that returns the value of the function (1 row, 1 cell). Then I set the field to something along the lines of DLookup("UserID","ViewName"). Voila!